# Give TextView a variable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I'm trying to set a text on a TextView using a val

```
class shoeDetails : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityShoeDetailsBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityShoeDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shoe_details)

 val title =   intent.getStringExtra("Title")
 val model =   intent.getStringExtra("Model")
 val kmused = intent.getStringExtra("KmUsed")?.toFloat()
 val kmestimated =   intent.getStringExtra("KmEstimated")?.toFloat()

    binding.textView12.text = model
    binding.textView10.text = title
    binding.textView15.text = kmused.toString()
    binding.textView16.text = kmestimated.toString()
```

When I print on console the values are arriving, but the text never changes on the UI

Comment: Kindly show your whole `Activty` or `Fragment` code.

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0 updated original post, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the initialized `view` variable. Use `binding.root` inside `setContentView` like this:

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are sending data on correct way,
remember use the same name of your key string,
and use Binding:

setContentView(view)